# steps to install simmechanics_to_urdf?

Tags: xml, ros

I'm quite new to ros and gazebo and would like to know how to convert my xml to urdf.

I tried installing simmechanics_to_urdf but have been unable to use it. ros says package error. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? [Please see here how to ask a comprehensive question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ros shows package error and i have been unavailable to find the package in the rospack list